# error while calling procedure from Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have a stored procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(xmlVal xml, counter integer, OUT xmlOut xml, OUT state integer, OUT err text)...
```

calling it from Hibernate as

```
em.createStoredProcedureQuery("test")
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter("xmlVal", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter("counter", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter("xmlOut", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter("state", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter("err", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
                .setParameter("xmlVal", xml)
                .setParameter("counter", 2).execute();
```

The Error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function test(character varying, integer) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 15

Postgresql version 9.6.5
Hibernate version 5.3
Environment wildfly 20
```

What to do?

Comment: My guess is the problem is your PG function has a first parameter of type XML but your declaration in Hibernate makes it a String.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I had to change a query in a question post to

```
em.createNativeQuery("select xmlOutput as xmlOutput, state as state, message as message from test(CAST(?1 AS XML), CAST(?2 AS int4))").setParameter(1, xml)
                .setParameter(2, 2)
                .unwrap(NativeQuery.class)
                .addScalar("xmlOutput", new StringType())
                .addScalar("state", new IntegerType())
                .addScalar("message", new StringType()).getResultList();
```

To sum it up, had to go with native query.

Answer (score 0):

> I suppose you are setting the wrong parameter when calling this
> function. If you use psql use the short cut command \df to get all
> functions you built and check this again ... such an error message is
> mostly a hint that something with the params is wrong ...
>
> if this has not be done already ;-)